Do I still have to place Gradle's jar in my repo in 2024?
When distros have Gradle nicely packaged for 20 years, and my builds are on GitHub with uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@v3 or whatever is the recommended way to have the latest Gradle version on the build host: What is the proper way to configure a modern Java (Android) project using Gradle? Do I still need to litter my source with gradlew, gradle.jar, etc?

Answer is no.
i've been dealing with old java projects for too long... And the "wrapper method" is still the recommended from their docs. But not using it is trivial.
Just had to delete all the "hardcoded" gradle stuff, and replace ./gradlew with gradle on my build scripts.
